# Unknown column in a table

Tags: mysql

```
Create schema Nevy;

create table sailor
(
  sid INT(5) NOT NULL,
  sname Varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  rating INT(5) NOT NULL,
  age INT(5) Not NULL,
  primary key (sid));

Create table reserve
(
  sid INT(5) NOT NULL,
  bid INT(5) NOT NULL,
  DAYT date NOT NULL,
  primary key (sid,bid,dayt),
  foreign key (bid) references boat(bid),
  foreign key (sid) references sailor(sid)
);

Create Table boat
(
  bid INT(5) NOT NULL,
  bname VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  primary key (bid) );


INSERT INTO nevy.sailor 
values(22,'Dustin',7,45),(29,'Brutus',1,33),
  (31,'Lubber',8,55.5),(32,'Andy',8,25.5),
  (58,'Rusty',10,35),(64,'Horatio',7,35),
  (71,'zorba',10,16), (74,'Horatio',9,35),
  (85,'Art',3,25.5),(95,'Bob',3,63.5);

INSERT INTO nevy.boat 
values(101,'interlake','blue'),(102,'Interlake','red'),
  (103,'Clipper','green'),(104,'Marine','Red');

INSERT INTO nevy.reserve 
values (22,101,'1998-10-10'),(22,102,'1998-10-10'),
  (22,103,'1998-8-10'),(22,104,'1998-7-10'),
  (31,102,'1998-10-11'),(31,103,'1998-6-11'),
  (31,104,'1998-12-11'),(64,101,'1998-5-9'),
  (64,102,'1998-8-9'),(74,103,'1998-8-9');

select sname 
from sailor 
Where sailor.sid= reserve.sid 
  AND bid=103;
```

When I execute the last select statement , it gives me the error

> unknown column: reserve.sid

I don't know why this error is being generated.

Comment: `FROM sailor, reserve` is what you need. Also flagged for removal due to basic nature of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being generated because you currently aren't joining your `sailor` table to `reserve` so the engine doesn't have any reference to the `reserve` table.

In order to make the `reserve` table available, you'll need to JOIN the tables on the `sid` column similar to:

```
select s.sname 
from sailor s
inner join reserve r
  on s.sid= r.sid 
where r.bid=103;
```

Or if you just want to return the `sname` that exists in the `reserve` table, then you could use `EXISTS`:

```
select s.sname
from sailor s
where exists (select 1 
              from reserve r
              where bid = 103
                and s.sid = r.sid);
```

If you needed to include all 3 tables in a single query, then you would use:

```
select s.name
from sailor s
inner join reserve r
  on s.sid = r.sid
inner join boat b
  on r.bid = b.bid
```

Comment: why we use sailor s or reserve r. i mean to say s or r.

Comment: @user61052 Those are aliases for each table. You don't need to use them, but it saves keystrokes by not having to fully type each table name.

Comment: how to inner join three tables? syntax

Comment: @user61052 You'd add the 3 table using another `INNER JOIN` and you would join `ON` the column the tables share - see my edit.

Comment: plz by looking at the above tables sailor,boat,reserve: how i can write a query to compute increments for the ratings of persons who have sailed two different boats on the same date or dayt

Comment: @user61052 That's a different question, ask a new one - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask